# Refresh in dialog

Tags: aem

I have dropdown options where options populate dynamically, I have a multifield,checkbox,dropdown. When i click on the checkbox[event on selectionchanged] its fetch the items count from multifield and display options.

```
var select2opts = [];
    var dialog = this.findParentByType('dialog');
    var panel1 = this.findParentByType('panel');
    var dropdown = panel1.getComponent("dropdown1");
    var button = panel1.getComponent("button1");
    var customfield = panel1.getComponent("customfield");
    for (var i = 1; i <= customfield.items.getCount()-1 ; i++)   {
    select2opts.push({value: i, text:"Tab "+i});
    }
    dropdown.setOptions(select2opts);
    dropdown.show();
```

But Rather than checkbox, i want some image to be place there like refresh & on click this function will get call. Which type of widget and event i can use for that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **button** xtype. It has a **icon** property that takes url of the image to be used. Set your function as the value of **handler** property. The handler function gets called every time the button is clicked. button and event objects are passed to the handler function. The button object can be used to get reference to the dialog object.

Reference : http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/output/CQ.Ext.Button.html

Comment: Hi, I have used button, Now my button is coming with handler, But my button is taking width of whole panel. If i set the width property it doesn't effect.Any Idea

Comment: set width property as string and also set the anchor property to **form** (string)